# Does momentum scale linearly with time, assuming a constant nonzero net force, even at relativistic speeds?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, momentum, reference-frames

I would expect it to, since you'd think the loss of velocity due to relativity would be made up for by the gain in relativistic mass. I'd like this to be confirmed, though.

and if so, in whose reference frame? the object's or the initial rest frame?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using "relativistic mass". The strength of the concept is that it preserve non-relativistic formulae such as:

$F = ma$

and

$\frac{dp}{dt} = F$.

which was valuable in 1916, but is dated in 2016. It's more productive to work in Minkowski space, where rest mass:

$mc^2 = \sqrt{E^2-(pc)^2} $

is a four-scalar (the same in all frames), and the four-momentum is:

$ p^{\mu} = mu^{\mu} $

with $u^{\mu}$ being the four-velocity:

$ u^{\mu} = \gamma(c, {\bf{\vec{v}}}) $.

Thus, mass is constant, and the Lorentz factor is part of the four-velocity--where is plays the important geometric roll of keeping the magnitude of your four-velocity through space-time equal to the speed of light.

Then 4-momentum changes in response to 4-force according to:

$\frac{dp^{\mu}}{d\tau} = F^{\mu} $.

This is a manifestly covariant view, and can be evaluated in any reference frame (or slice of simultaneity) you like.